# Filter json response from http request to only specific value then select the largest 'id' value from all results

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, filter, response

I have a Python script where I would like to filter Python with a http get and I would like to filter the response data for only specific values. The json response example is below:

```
{
  "id": "38",
  "name": "Report1",
  "description": "",
  "reportDefinitionID": "-1",
  "jobID": "105600",
  "type": "csv",
  "status": "Completed",
  "creator": {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "btest",
    "firstname": "bob",
    "lastname": "test"
  },
  {
  "id": "39",
  "name": "Report2",
  "description": "",
  "reportDefinitionID": "-1",
  "jobID": "113218",
  "type": "csv",
  "status": "Completed"
  "creator": {
     "id": "1",
      "username": "btest1",
      "firstname": "Bob",
      "lastname": "test1"
  },
  "id": "49",
  "name": "Report1",
  "description": "",
  "reportDefinitionID": "-1",
  "jobID": "113219",
  "type": "csv",
  "status": "Completed"
  "creator": {
     "id": "1",
      "username": "btest1",
      "firstname": "Bob",
      "lastname": "test1"
  }
```

I would like to filter the above json to only show a report by name. For example if there is a Python filter that would only allow me to filter for a report by the name of "Report1". If I filtered on name of "Report1". I would expect to following to be to be returned below:

```
{
  "id": "38",
  "name": "Report1",
  "description": "",
  "reportDefinitionID": "-1",
  "jobID": "105600",
  "type": "csv",
  "status": "Completed",
  "creator": {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "btest",
    "firstname": "bob",
    "lastname": "test"
  },
  "id": "49",
  "name": "Report1",
  "description": "",
  "reportDefinitionID": "-1",
  "jobID": "113219",
  "type": "csv",
  "status": "Completed"
  "creator": {
     "id": "1",
      "username": "btest1",
      "firstname": "Bob",
      "lastname": "test1"
  }
```

For the final part of the script I would like to compare the 'id' field to show the largest value for example id 38 vs id 49 and then output the json for the largest in this case id 49. I would like it output

```
},
"id": "49",
"name": "Report1",
"description": "",
"reportDefinitionID": "-1",
"jobID": "113219",
"type": "csv",
"status": "Completed"
"creator": {
   "id": "1",
    "username": "btest1",
    "firstname": "Bob",
    "lastname": "test1"
}
```

For the last part i would just like to save the id value '49' to a variable in Python.

So far what I have below is:

```
    response_data = response.json()

    input_dict = json.dumps(response_data)

    input_transform = json.loads(input_dict)

    # Filter python objects with list comprehensions

    sort1 = sorted([r.get("id") for r in input_transform if r.get("name") == "Report1"], reverse=True)[0]

    # Print sorted JSON

    print(sort1)
```

I updated my code and now I'm getting the error below:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I researched it and can not figure out what I'm doing now and how to get past it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the ID in the listcomp as bellow:

```py
sorted([r.get("id") for r in sample if r.get("name") == "Report1"], reverse=True)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks so much i tried this out by adding it into my poc code but I got  the error "'str' object has no attribute 'get'" , please see above updated code

Comment: My sample poc code looks like this ```    response_data = response.json()
    
    input_dict = json.dumps(response_data)
    
    input_transform = json.loads(input_dict)

    # Filter python objects with list comprehensions

    sort1 = sorted([r.get("id") for r in input_transform if r.get("name") == "Report1"], reverse=True)[0]
    
    # Print sorted JSON
    
    print(sort1)

Comment: I recommend you to verify the objects type inside input_transform using the function `type()`. Eg: type(input_transform). They need to be a dict when you use in the listcomp.